# Is there any API or sample code available for Pinterest Integration in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, pinterest

i want to integrate Pinterest in my iPhone Application so user can directly set Pin or like from  iPhone Application. is there any tutorials or sample code available for it.is there any official site for get API for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this moment there is no official public API for Pinterest available.

[Source](http://www.itweb.co.za/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52696)

**Update:** Pinterest has introduced an API for developers, available [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/?).

Comment: link is expire.. please how to use api

Answer (score 1):

Pinterest now has an iOS SDK though at the current time you are limited to sharing images: https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/